# How can I avoid database hanging in oracle?

Tags: php, oracle

I have a php application which connects to a database which has only two tables : `users` and `folders`. When you login in the application and press a button, a huge number of records are being inserted in the `folders` table. The process takes about 15 minutes to complete. In this time, all the application gets stuck. In my application's header I have something like

```
select * from users where id = {$_SESSION['user_id']}
```

but until those tens of thousands of records are inserted in the `folders` table, the second query just isn't executed. After I wait 15 minutes and the import gets done, I can access any page I want. How can I fix this problem?

A very important thing that I initially forgot to mention (my apologies for that), is an oracle database. I tested it earlier for MySql (just for curiosity) and it works with no problems but for oracle it seems to have this issue. The connection is made using OCI8.

Comment: Which part is the problem?? Is it supposed to insert that many records? Or is the problem that you want to access the page while this process is going on?

Comment: What makes it so slow? Does it read the file system for folders to insert into the DB? A few "tens of thousands of records" should not take 15 minutes. You could potentially save some time using prepared statements ("where id = ?"). But your best bet would probably be to have the button fire off a job to a task queue which runs either with cron or a task runner or something. Running it in the background will at least remove your problem with the application "crashing"

Comment: More information will help.  Is this a web application? If so, is the web page hung up waiting for your bulk load to finish? Or, does some other user of the web site get hung up waiting for the one-row `users` table query?

Comment: Yes, is a web application built in PHP. The problem is this : the import.php file reads from a remote database 20.000+ records and inserts them into my table. While the import is executed, if, for example I want to run the users.php file where I want to run another query (select * from users) the second query doesn't run until that import is finished. Is like the database gets blocked by the other.

Answer (score 3):

The 15 minute population should happen in a background task, Its then trivial to see if the user exists. If not show some sort of message to the user.

For example githubs fork feature, You see a book being scanned until the background task has been completed.

This can be done by having a third table with a user id and processed column. Background task is looking for processed = 0 and processing.

The user is looking for processed = 1 to continue, if processed = 0 show a friendly page.

When the procssing has complete in the background, then update the flag in the DB

Answer (score 2):

I think you should make a separate `longprocess.php` file and use `header()` to redirect it to `shortprocess.php`. Now user won't have to wait because `longprocess.php` will exit after 15mins and `shortprocess.php` will send data to user without delay.

**longprocess.php**

```
<?php 
header('Location: shortprocess.php');
//time taking sql query here
exit;
?>
```

P.S. since both `php` files will use seperate DB connection so it might not effect other scripts performance.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers and efforts but the mistake was on me : it turns out the problem was not from the database but from the PHP's session. In the header, before executing the query, I use 'session_start()' without session_write_close(). So, after the session_start() call, I started the 15 minutes query. Any attempt to view another page in that time was impossible because the session_write_close function was not called yet (it gets automatically called when the script ends) and that gave me the impression that the database was blocking the script but in fact it was my PHP code that was wrong.